# Johann Bernoulli did not fully understand logarithms?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, logarithms, math-history

This [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula) article makes the claim:

"Bernoulli's correspondence with Euler (who also knew the above equation) shows that Bernoulli did not fully understand logarithms."

This is found under "History" . What does wikipedia mean here? Surely, Bernoulli understood what a logarithm was.

Comment: Pure speculation on my part, but perhaps they mean complex logarithms. The logarithm $\log:\mathbb{R}^+ \to \mathbb{R}$ is much simpler.

Comment: @nullUser looks like you were right

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to Bradley and Sandifer, eds., Leonhard Euler: Life, Work and Legacy, pages 259-260, Bernoulli, in correspondence with Euler, 1727-29, asserted $\log(-x)=\log x$. There's more to it than that, the book goes into some detail.

Comment: So I guess nulluser was right